# TypeLite generation with adding hirarchal dependency

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript1.5, typelite

I'm currently using a Client build with AngularJS 1.x in TypeScript and an AspNet WebApi Backend in C#.

For communication with the backend I use the $resource-Service from angular. By using this service, my model interfaces generated with TypeLITE have to extend

```
ng.resource.IResource<IModel>
```

Is it possible to automatically extend all generated model interfaces from this interface described by angular?

Otherwise all has to be done separatly like this

```
export interface Model extends ng.resource.IResource<Model> {
}
```

Many thanks in advance,
MacX

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a straightforward task. An option is to create a custom `TsModelVisitor` that adds dummy class `ng.resource.IResource<T>` to the code model and modifies base class for all other classes in the code model.

I would try following steps:

- create a class that derives from TsModelVisitor

  - in `VisitModel` method create a new `TsClass` model that represents angular model interface
  - in `VisitClass` method set `BaseType` to the class created in `VisitModel` method for every class
- call your model visitor in .tt file

  ```
  var ts = TypeScript.Definitions()
               .AsConstEnums(false);
  var model = ts.ModelBuilder.Build();
  model.RunVisitor(new YourModelVisitor());
  ```
- instead of `<#= ts.Generate(TsGeneratorOutput.Properties) #>` use '<#= ts.ScriptGenerator.Generate(model, TsGeneratorOutput.Properties) #>' to generate output

Comment: Thanks so far. Will try to implement it this way. Will get in contact afterwards

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this to extend the `TsGenerator`.  Create a file named `TsAngularJsModelGenerator.ttinclude` in the same directory as your `TypeLite.Net4.tt` file, and paste the following:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)\TypeLite.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)\TypeLite.Net4.dll"#>

<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="TypeLite" #> 
<#@ import namespace="TypeLite.TsModels" #> 

<#+
class TsAngularJsModelGenerator : TsGenerator
{
    protected override void AppendClassDefinition(TsClass classModel, ScriptBuilder sb, TsGeneratorOutput generatorOutput)
    {

        string typeName = this.GetTypeName(classModel);
        string visibility = this.GetTypeVisibility(classModel, typeName) ? "export " : "";
        sb.AppendFormatIndented("{0}interface {1}", visibility, typeName);
        if (classModel.BaseType != null)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat(" extends {0}", this.GetFullyQualifiedTypeName(classModel.BaseType));
        }
        else
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("  extends ng.resource.IResource<{0}>", typeName);
        }
        sb.AppendLine(" {");
        var members = new List<TsProperty>();
        if ((generatorOutput & TsGeneratorOutput.Properties) == TsGeneratorOutput.Properties)
            members.AddRange(classModel.Properties);
        if ((generatorOutput & TsGeneratorOutput.Fields) == TsGeneratorOutput.Fields)
            members.AddRange(classModel.Fields);
        using (sb.IncreaseIndentation())
        {
            foreach (var property in members)
            {
                if (property.IsIgnored)
                    continue;
                var propTypeName = this.GetPropertyType(property);
                sb.AppendLineIndented(string.Format("{0}: {1};", this.GetPropertyName(property), propTypeName));
            }
        }
        sb.AppendLineIndented("}");
        _generatedClasses.Add(classModel);
    }
} #>
```

**Note:** You will probably need to change the first two lines to point to a valid location for you (I found that under MVC the `bin` directory doesn't always contain the `TypeLite.dll` and `TypeLite.Net4.dll` binaries - if you are having difficulties remember to set the value of `debug` to `true` in the first line of the `TypeLite.Net4.tt` file to get better diagnostics).

Next, add to your `TypeLite.Net4.tt` file the following line under the line `<#@include file="Manager.ttinclude"#>`:

```
<#@include file="TsAngularJsModelGenerator.ttinclude"#>
```

Lastly, in the `TypeLite.Net4.tt` file change the call to `TypeScript.Definitions`, passing a new instance of `TsAngularJsModelGenerator` as follows:

```
<# var ts = TypeScript.Definitions(new TsAngularJsModelGenerator())
    .WithReference("Enums.ts")
    .ForLoadedAssemblies();
#>
```